# It is an existential question

Tags: semantics, syntactic-analysis, dummy-it

A question on another site asks, *I have a laptop ... Now I am trying to install Windows 7 and it shows a message saying "Driver not found".*

Whereupon a commenter asks,  *What is the "it" that shows the message?*

I would think that was an existential ***it***, which cannot be attributed to anything in particular. In any case, if I had structured the question myself, I would probably have intended so.

**Q**: Is this a case of an existential ***it***?

---

[Edit-1] Clarification
This question is *not* about the subject of the example. The question relates to English language, grammar and esp., the concept of the ***existential it***. Please see also the tags for an idea.

Comment: No. This is a case of *it* being used as a pronoun substitution for Windows 7 or the laptop or some other agent that popped up the message — *not* in the sense of "things in general."

Comment: I don't understand the edit. If it's not about the subject of the example, what's the point of the example?

Comment: What Robusto said. It would be an "existential it" (like the one starting this sentence) if the phrasing were *Now I am trying to install Windows 7 and **it** seems there is a problem, indicated by a message saying "Driver not found".*

Comment: @slim RE "not about the example", I think what the poster meant is that he is not asking for someone to explain what the error message means or how to install Windows 7 properly, but rather he is asking about the grammer of the sentence that happens to use installing Windows 7 as an example.

Answer (score 7):

Yes the "it" refers to something concrete. Exactly what is not entirely clear, but ambiguity is not the same as existential. The questioner is probably referring to the laptop, Windows 7, the installation process or a similarly nebulous concept (Sorry David Schwartz!). The concept is only nebulous if you understand the detail and know that there are significant differences between different parts of the system giving this message.

From the questioner's perspective, the whole "laptop, process, windows" thing is a concrete object - a laptop installing Windows 7. The problem comes because what they see as a single thing others see as a set of many things.  However, for the language issue as seen from the questioner's perspective, *it* identifies a concrete "laptop installing windows" thing that gives the error message.

Comment: +1 The explanation can't be any better than this.

Comment: @jwpat7 disagreed...... Thank you! My typing is not always what it should be.

Answer (score 6):

It most certainly can be attributed to something in particular.

"It" could be a dialog box that pops up during the install.

"It" could be a line of text, before the installer has gone into a graphical mode.

This *it* is ambiguous, but not existential. It could mean the laptop, Windows 7 -- two nouns that appear in the quotation -- or any number of implied entities; the installer program, a dialog box, and so on.

(I would expect that most non-technical people would conceptualise it as *the laptop* showing a message; the questioner is asking for clarification.).

Comment: As the questioner in question, I can confirm that your interpretation is the correct one. The "it" could be the installer, the BIOS, the Windows boot manager, or any of a number of other things. The person asking the original questions seems to imagine we know exactly what part of the lengthy process of installing Windows produced that error, but we have no idea.

Answer (score 0):

Can't it be attributed to the operating **system**, it is *Windows 7* telling the user that the *driver is not found*. Beyond the system, you could attribute the message to the developers of the system.

Comment: I agree. However, only if you are sure that the *it* is indeed referring to something concrete. (We are concerned with the *it* in English grammar here.)

Comment: I probably don't understand the question sorry, an operating system isn't something concrete?

Comment: The question is about whether the *it* is really supposed to refer to something at all? Or is it like the *it* in "It is raining outside." Hope that clarifies.

Comment: @Kris It surely does refer to something. It could be the BIOS, the Windows pre-install program, the Windows installer program pre-reboot, the Windows installer post-reboot, the BIOS, the newly-installed Windows sysytem, or any of a number of other things involved in the process of installing Windows. If the person writing the question intended it as existential, then part of my point is that *something* displayed that message and it *matters* what it was that did it.

Answer (score -1):

If I say

> *and it shows a message*

then *it* is something concrete that shows a message.

If I don't want to refer to anything concrete, then I phrase

> *and a message is shown*

Thus, I daresay that *it* is something concrete, but it could, of course, refer to anything.

Comment: *Phrase* without an object can't be right.  The usual wording would be *It is phrased* or *I phrase it as*, but both use the 'existential it' OP is asking about.