# Why don’t other pronouns get to albe-themselves, à la albeit’s “it”?

Tags: conjunctions, word-formation

- YES:
  "Euthanizing this particular kitten was a traumatic, **albeit** humane necessity."
- NO:
  "The geese, having pooped everywhere, made for hideous pets, **albethem** delicious as an entree."
- NO:
  "Most of the pigs were oblivious, **albethose** closer to the pen showed increasing anxiety."

Why does *albeit* have no pronoun kin? (*Albeshe, albethis*, etc.)

Comment: For the same reason that he is not cold outside today.

Comment: Right, albethat not exactly what I asked. lol.

Comment: Actually Jeff is spot on. "It's cold outside today" is probably the canonical example of the dummy pronoun at work.

Comment: Related: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/58329/it-is-an-existential-question

Comment: Although both answers give some insight, I have doubts. If, as they both claim, "albeit" is a contraction of "although be it that" -- would it not be necessary to say, in the 2nd example: ".. pets, albeit *they are* delicious as an entree"? And would I reformulate my first clause as "Albeit both answers giving some insight" or "Albeit both answers *give* ...", only the second one being in line with the theory of the answers --?

Answer (score 23):

Because the *it* in *albeit* is the "[dummy it](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/5758/what-does-it-refer-to-in-its-raining)". It's a contraction of "although be it that". There is no such thing as a "dummy them" or a "dummy those" in English.

Comment: Yes, it's/*they're a long way to Tipperary and a long way to Kerry.

Comment: The *it* may be a dummy, but is *albe* for real? Is "albe" a prefix? Only because it joins with *it*? I'm unaware of it.

Comment: @John Lawler - Why do you use the asterisk before 'they're'?

Comment: @AngloSaxon: asterisks are used by linguists to indicate that what's following is ungrammatical.

Comment: Right. It's to mark that sinking feeling you get in the pit of your stomach when you realize you've said something wrong, like _*She gave them it_ or _*She she looked up it._

Comment: @John Lawler: Agreed it's a *slightly* odd construction, but I don't really have a problem with *"He gave me it"*. Nor is it obvious to me why *"it"* should be different to *"this"* - and I certainly can't see any problem at all with *"They gave me **this**"*.

Comment: OK, if those don't move you, how about a [Ross Constraint](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/aue/ross.html) violation: _*That's the book that Bill married the woman who illustrated._

Comment: This answer is fundamentally flawed. Wonder how it got up votes at all. For a partial insight into what the *it* in albeit is, see the answer by @Shoe. Up voters may please exercise great discretion.

Answer (score 15):

*Albeit* is a contraction of *although be it that*, meaning something like *although it is the case that*.  So:

- That's a cool handbag, albeit expensive

means

- That's a cool handbag, although it is the case that it is expensive

And:

- Those are cool handbags, albeit expensive

means

- Those are cool handbags, although it is the case that they are expensive

As RegDwight states, the *it* in *albeit* is a dummy subject; it is not an anaphoric (backward) reference to any specific noun in the preceding expression. This is why words such as *albeshe* do not exist.

Comment: It's sort of like French's "Qu'est-ce que c'est", which I always found obscene to write, but sexy and useful to say.