# Collective equivalent of 'albeit'?

Tags: grammar, word-choice, word-usage

I was after the collective equivalent of *albeit*, if such a word exists?

Here's what I used:

> There are some packages and tools available (albe them nowhere near as mature as those found in other frameworks and ecosystems).

The recipient knew exactly what was meant. Just curious to know if this (or 'albethem') is 'correct' English and if not was was there a better alternative?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why don’t other pronouns get to albe-themselves, à la albeit’s “it”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/65519/why-don-t-other-pronouns-get-to-albe-themselves-%c3%a0-la-albeit-s-it)

Answer (score 18):

You do not need a "collective equivalent", ***albeit*** is a conjunction that means *although* ([Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/albeit)). So it is not a relative pronoun that would need agreement in person or number.

The word comes

> From the Middle English expression ***al be it (that)***, itself shortened from ***althagh it be that*** (“although it be that”), and thus composed from ***al*** (“completely, entirely”) +‎ ***be*** (3rd person singular present subjunctive of been (“to be”)) +‎ ***it***. ([Wikipedia](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/albeit))

However, you are not the only person who thought that there should be such an agreement. Wikipedia notes that:

> Rarely, ***albethey*** is used when the meaning is “despite (the multiple things) being” rather than “despite (the single thing) being”; *this is nonstandard, based on a **flawed interpretation** of albeit.*

The ***it*** in *albeit* is the [dummy subject](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/dummy-subjects) of ***be***. I have tried to find a reference stating that, but I couldn't find one.

Answer (score 1):

To note that the plural does exist but not as a single word:

> c1225  (▸?c1200)    Hali Meiðhad (Bodl.) (1940) l. 632   [Pride] bihalt eche wununge alle hire modres, *al beon ha meidnes*.

> 1659   T. Fuller Appeal Iniured Innocence ii. 94   From whence came Smith, *al be he Knight or Squire*, But from the Smith that forgeth at the fire.

> 1876   R. T. Fisher Rakings over Many Seasons 4   *All be they worthless*, yet will I..rake things up.

> 1999   K. Comer Landscapes New West p. x   With our two (*all be they beautiful*) boys.